Безопасно ли использовать переменную цикла после цикла?
Допустим у меня есть особый словарь, о котором я знаю, что в нём с некоторым шансом может оказаться ключ пустой строки. И если в нём и в правду будет ключ пустой строки, то он всегда будет на первом месте
dict_ex = {"":"Aaa", "Bb":"b", 1:"Cc", "Ddd":123}
Если я сделаю так:
def Aaa():

    for dk in dict_ex.keys():
        break

    if dk!="":
        print(dk)

    return None

Aaa()

Надёжно ли будет читать из переменной для цикла после его выполнения?
Мало ли есть какие-то подводные камни, или иные питонические прелести, о которых я не знаю.

В общем случае не очень, если коллекция из цикла была пустая, то переменная не будет создана

Если до цикла инициализировать переменную, то безопасно.

Но ведь словарь - неупорядоченная структура данных. Поэтому нельзя полагаться на то, что какой-то ключ всегда будет на первом месте. Или это действительно "особый" словарь с такой гарантией?

@AlexanderPetrov, кажется, начиная с Python 3.7 словарь помнит порядок элементов. P.S., да начиная c 3.7 гарантируется, но фактически уже было в 3.6: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40007169/4752653

Да, в Питоне переменная цикла после окончания цикла сохраняет своё значение и доступна. Но в данном случае гораздо лучше не полагаться на особенности реализации словаря в Питоне, а использовать тот факт, что проверка наличия ключей в словаре имеет сложность O(1) (амортизированное), т.е. если у ваших элементов словаря не вырожденный хэш, то поиск будет произведён моментально. Ну и первый элемент итерируемой коллекции можно получить без цикла for. В общем, я бы использовал примерно такие проверки и получение 1-го элемента, если это нужно:
dict_ex = {"Bb":"b", 1:"Cc", "Ddd":123}
if "" not in dict_ex:
    if dict_ex:
        print(next(iter(dict_ex)))

Тут в явном виде проверяется, что ключ "" есть в словаре, что словарь не пустой, и в этом случае печатается первый из ключей.
Хотя в любом случае словарь обычно принято считать неупорядоченной структурой. И если вам нужно как-то выделить отдельный ключ, лучше бы его записывать в отдельную переменную, например.
